# Installing Serf version 1.2.1 for SVN compile with http and https. Redhat 5 machine

Tags: linux, subversion

Running a `make` command gives this error.

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lexpat collect2: ld returned 1 exit status make: *** [test/serf_get] Error 1
Other logs:- $ld -lexpat --verbose
attempt to open /usr/x86_64-redhat-linux/lib64/libexpat.so failed
attempt to open /usr/x86_64-redhat-linux/lib64/libexpat.a failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib64/libexpat.so failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib64/libexpat.a failed
attempt to open /lib64/libexpat.so failed
attempt to open /lib64/libexpat.a fai`enter code here`led
attempt to open /usr/lib64/libexpat.so failed
attempt to open /usr/lib64/libexpat.a failed
attempt to open /usr/x86_64-redhat-linux/lib/libexpat.so failed
attempt to open /usr/x86_64-redhat-linux/lib/libexpat.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib64/libexpat.so failed
attempt to open /usr/lib64/libexpat.a failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib/libexpat.so failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib/libexpat.a failed
attempt to open /lib/libexpat.so failed
attempt to open /lib/libexpat.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/libexpat.so failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/libexpat.a failed
ld: cannot find -lexpat
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install `expat-devel`:

```
yum install expat-devel
```

That will provide the library your build is looking for.